# How can I create PIE chart using 1 Dimensions and Aggregated Measures

Tags: tableau-api

Why is Tableau not able to generate PIE chart when we use one dimension and one aggregated measure?

Comment: Could you provide somem ore information? Maybe some code?

Comment: Better question. Why are you trying to generate a pie chart? :-)

Comment: Pie charts are visually appealing in some cases

Comment: I found out you can't select pie chart if your measure is an AGG() function, but it worked for a sum function. You can either follow the steps or use a sum function for your measure then replace it with an AGG function.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau can generate pie charts using 1 dimension and 1 aggregated measure.

Selected the pie chart. Use the dimension as Color, and the measure as Angle. And select what kind of measure you want to do (sum, count, ...), if it's not aggregated yet.

Send some example of what is not working